# Verify with a for loop if numbers are increasing in a list

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I have tried to create a function helping me to specify if my list "inc" is a list composed of increasing numbers. In the end, if I have a list of `[1,2,3]`, I am expecting output as `True` and `False` when I have a list like `[1,2,1]`. With the following code, I get not the expected output which should be `True`.

```py
inc=[1, 2, 3]
        
def increase(inc):  
    result = True 
    for i in range(0, len(inc)-1):
        if inc[i] > inc[i-1]: 
            return result
        else:
            return False
      
print(increase(inc))
output=False
```

Comment: `if inc[i] > inc[i-1]`, you still don't know if the list is in increasing order, as you can only be sure of that when reaching the end, so you can't `return` yet.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille very obvious !! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

How about using sorted() function that returns a sorted list?

```
inc=[1, 2, 3] # try swapping items in the list
if sorted(inc) == inc:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few problems here. It returns False because lst[-1] is indeed bigger than lst[0]; you should start the range from 1.
In addition, it should return True only if the condition is True for all the iterations, not right after the first iteration.